# Can't install WatchKit app on Apple Watch Keep Loading Blank Screen Display

Tags: ios, loading, watchapp

I have added watch app into my existing project. In my app there is location services. when try to run watch app into simulator it was working fine But when try to install into Apple Watch Device app keeps loading and blank black screen display.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

After long I found solution and it works for me. I have removed **Required device capabilities** key from .plist of Watch Extension. And its works.